# Rendering Images on GitHub Pages with Astro

Tags: image, github-pages, astrojs

I am attempting to create a small test site using **Astro** and deploying it on GitHub Pages. This is my first time using Astro and **deploying to GitHub Pages**. I have followed the instructions on Astro's site to deploy the website and have looked up other methods of deployment, but I'm still experiencing problems rendering my images. **The images aren't rendering at all, at most the alt text is displayed.**

The full repository is located [here](https://github.com/Mia703/test-project).

But, for brevity, smaller code pieces are located here.

The GitHub workflow is the following below:

```yaml
# Sample workflow for building and deploying an Astro site to GitHub Pages

name: Deploy Astro CI to GitHub Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out your repository using git
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup and use Node 20
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20'
          cache: 'npm'
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      
      - name: Build with Astro
        run: npm run build --if-present
      
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
        with:
          path: ./dist

  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v3
```

And currently, images are being referenced as:

```js
const GENPATH = "../../public/";

const project_data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        projectName: "Testimonial Grid Challenge",
        projectDescription:
            "Challenged by Front-end Mentor to build a testimonials grid section using HTML, CSS, and CSS Grid.",
        projectCreationDate: "December 8, 2022",
        projectHashTagCollection: [
            {
                tag: "#Web_Dev",
            },
        ],
        projectGitLink:
            "https://github.com/Mia703/FrontEnd-Mentor----Testimonials-Grid",
        projectLiveLink:
            "https://mia703.github.io/FrontEnd-Mentor----Testimonials-Grid/",
        projectImageCollection: [
            {
                image: GENPATH + "testimonials-1-desktop.png",
                alt: "Testimonial Grid Challenge - Desktop",
            },
            {
                image: GENPATH + "testimonials-2-tablet.png",
                alt: "Testimonial Grid Challenge - Tablet",
            },
            {
                image: GENPATH + "testimonials-3-mobile.png",
                alt: "Testimonial Grid Challenge - Mobile",
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

In HTML, the images are placed like this:

```html
<div class="project-gallery-container">
    {
        projectImageCollection.map((element) => (
            <img
                src={element.image}
                alt={element.alt}
                decoding="async"
                loading="lazy"
                class="gallery-item"
            />
        ))
    }
</div>
```

I'd appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: The images aren't rendering and I'm not sure what the issue is. The only thing that displays is the image alt text.

Comment: It looks like the relative paths have one `../` too many. I'm not familiar with Astro, but it looks like you have to modify `GENPATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, change `const GENPATH = "../../public/";` to `const GENPATH = "/test-project/";`

**The base property:** If you set `base="/test-project"` in your `astro.config` file (or equivalently run the build with `--base /test-project`), all references to pages and resources on your site must start with `"/test-project"`.

[The documentation](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#base) says about the `base` option:

> If you use this option, all imports and URLs of your static assets should add the base as a prefix. You can access this value via `import.meta.env.BASE_URL`.

You do this for the URLs of your links, e.g. in `nav_data.js`, where you specify the path for "About" as `path: "/test-project/about/"`.

You should do the same for the images. For example, you should replace

```
image: "../../public/news-1-desktop.png",
```

with

```
image: "/test-project/news-1-desktop.png",
```

Your use of `GENPATH` simplifies this. Replace

```
const GENPATH = "../../public/";
```

with

```
const GENPATH = "/test-project/";
```

The cited documentation suggests that as an alternative to hardcoding the base, you can also use

```
const GENPATH = import.meta.env.BASE_URL + "/";
```

In this case, the references always reflect the base value of your configuration.

**The build process:** The site works with Astro's DEV mode (started with `npm run dev`), but Astro issues warnings that URLs should not start with `/public`.

That the images are not found in the deployment is not specific to GitHub Pages. The effect is the same for a local build.

```
npm run build
npm run preview
```